# Is it ok to have a ton of white text in Atom text editor

Tags: atom-editor, text-editor

I just moved from Komodo text editor to Atom for multiple reasons. I was just wondering as I was working on a project and I happen to be seeing a ton of white text in my code. I know it is not a syntax error as it would be highlighted in red.

Comment: white text or white empty space?

Comment: white text was majority of what my code was

Comment: if it unexpectedly gives you problems just load the Whitespace extension and delete it.  Be sure to always have a backup of your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. There is an extension named Whitespace which allows you to delete whitespace if you wish. It has other options as well.

Comment: thanks a ton i was worried about this because the Komodo just gave me a bunch of squiggly lines whenever I wrote my code(which is why i switched) but i wasn't sure if it was the same way in Atom